# xml to html using xsl repeat

Tags: html, xslt, repeat

I have a problem, I have a xml file (page.xml), but a need tablem in HTML

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="page.xsl"?>

<AAAAA>

<ITEM>
<MANYTIMES>3</MANYTIMES>
<ID>010101</ID>
<NAME>name of item 1</NAME>
</ITEM>

<ITEM>
<MANYTIMES>5</MANYTIMES>
<ID>020202</ID>
<NAME>nme of item 2</NAME>
</ITEM>

</AAAAA>
```

I have xsl file (page.xsl):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1250"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html"/> 

<xsl:template match="/">
<html><body>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</body></html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/AAAAA/ITEM">
<xsl:variable name="howmanytimes"><xsl:value-of select="MANYTIMES"/></xsl:variable>

<div style='color:red'>View this <xsl:value-of select="$howmanytimes"/> many times:</div>

<TABLE>
<TR>
<TD style="border:solid windowtext 0.5pt;color:green"> <xsl:value-of select="ID"/> </TD>
<TD style="border:solid windowtext 0.5pt;color:blue"> <xsl:value-of select="NAME"/> </TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:styleshee
```

It's OK, but each table should be repeated `MANYTIMES`.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2.0, you can do

```
<xsl:variable name="here" select="."/>
<xsl:for-each select="1 to $howManyTimes">
   ...
</xsl:for-each>
```

You'll want to use the $here variable inside the loop, because the context item inside the loop is an integer, not a node.

There's no equivalent in XSLT 1.0, but there's a workaround provided the source document contains enough nodes:

```
<xsl:variable name="here" select="."/>
<xsl:for-each select="//node()[position() &lt;= $howManyTimes]">
   ...
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for help! I inserted a "for-each" loop into my file but it does not work. Probably something is wrong. I'm not a programmer, but I need to modify the display of this table. What is wrong?

Comment: If you're going to write programs then you're going to have to teach yourself the basics of programming. I'm afraid I can't tell you what's wrong without seeing all your code, but if you're only just starting to program then I don't think you can expect to get all your training by asking questions on StackOverflow. You wouldn't expect to drive a car without taking driving lessons.

Answer (score 0):

My changed file page.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1250"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html"/> 

<xsl:template match="/">
<html><body>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</body></html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/AAAAA/ITEM">
<xsl:variable name="howManyTimes"><xsl:value-of select="MANYTIMES"/></xsl:variable>

<div style='color:red'>View this <xsl:value-of select="$howManyTimes"/> many times:</div>


<!-- 
<TABLE>
<TR>
<TD style="border:solid windowtext 0.5pt;color:green"> <xsl:value-of select="ID"/> </TD>
<TD style="border:solid windowtext 0.5pt;color:blue"> <xsl:value-of select="NAME"/> </TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
-->

<xsl:for-each select="1 to $howManyTimes">
    <div> my text </div>
</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How I'll should use the for-each loop?

Comment: This is a supplementary question, not an answer.